# Fail to download Gradle plugin through IntelliJ build

Tags: gradle, intellij-idea

I have a company Gradle project which I'm working on at home. It is failing to build in IntelliJ. Specifically, it is failing to download a Gradle plugin (a Spring Boot one). The settings.gradle file looks like this

```
pluginManagement {
  repositories {
    maven { url "https://urlA" }
    maven { url "https://urlB" }
    gradlePluginPortal()
  }
}
rootProject.name = 'about'
```

When the build fails, I get this error

```
Plugin [id: 'org.springframework.boot', version: '2.3.3.RELEASE'] was not found in any of the following sources:

* Try:
Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.

* Exception is:
org.gradle.api.plugins.UnknownPluginException: Plugin [id: 'org.springframework.boot', version: '2.3.3.RELEASE'] was not found in any of the following sources:

- Gradle Core Plugins (plugin is not in 'org.gradle' namespace)
- Plugin Repositories (could not resolve plugin artifact 'org.springframework.boot:org.springframework.boot.gradle.plugin:2.3.3.RELEASE')
  Searched in the following repositories:
    maven(https://urlA)
    maven2(https://urlB)
    Gradle Central Plugin Repository
    <bunch of stack trace information here>
```

`urlA` is a URL for a network which is entirely air-gapped from the Internet. Yet oddly, the hostname in it actually resolves to an IP. I tried blocking this IP on my machine by running `route add -host urlAHost reject` thinking that would force Gradle to essentially ignore the that particular repo. No luck. `urlB` is for a host which is only accessible through a corporate VPN, which I have running.

The only way I can get this repo to build is to comment out the `maven` entry for `urlA`. I know that I could re-order the repositories and probably get this to work. However, none of my co-workers seem to have this issue and I'd rather understand what is going on with my machine in particular.

I'm using Gradle 6.5.1, IntelliJ Ultimate 2020.2.

Comment: Works fine here. Do you have proxies? Gradle will download the plugin automatically since it is available in Gradle plugin portal, see https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/gradle-plugin/reference/html/#getting-started If it can not download it - it could be a network configuration issue at your end.